# numpy: How to vectorize a function returning arrays of different shapes?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I need to vectorize a function that can return arrays of either shapes `(2,3)`, or `(3,3)`. Is it possible?

I create my vectorized function like this:

`my_func_v = np.vectorize(my_func, signature='()->(n,m)')`

And as long as the function returns only (2,3) or (3,3) arrays, it works well. But as soon as result shapes are mixed, numpy fails with the error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into
> shape (2,3)

Is it possible to mix returned shapes from a vectorized function?

Comment: What result do you expect? shape, dtype?  And why `np.vectorize`?

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for your comment. I would expect in return an array of arrays (inner arrays of shapes (2,3) and (3,3)). I use vectorize because I need to call pyvista.[cell_points](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.RectilinearGrid.cell_points.html) for a large number of cell ids. Just calling `cell_points` with the pv.array fails. (passing the np.array works with some numpy methods but not cell_points).

Comment: e.g. `mesh.cell_points(0)` works, but `mesh.cell_points(np.array([0]))` fails with an error `TypeError: GetCell argument 1: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. That's why I thought vectorize would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably shouldn't take the time since you haven't provided a minimal working example.  But let me illustrate `signature`:

```
In [190]: f = np.vectorize(lambda x: x * np.ones((2, 3), int), signature="()->(n,m)")
In [191]: f(np.arange(4))
Out[191]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
```

The return has the shape of the argument plus a (n,m).  And obviously for a numeric array those last 2 dimensions can't be mixed.  The above produces (4,2,3), below (2,2,2,3)

```
In [192]: f(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2))
Out[192]: 
array([[[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]]],


       [[[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]],

        [[3, 3, 3],
         [3, 3, 3]]]])
```

If I drop the signature, and specify object return type:

```
In [194]: f = np.vectorize(lambda x: x * np.ones((2, 3), int), otypes=['object'])
In [195]: f(np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2))
Out[195]: 
array([[array([[0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0]]), array([[1, 1, 1],
                                   [1, 1, 1]])],
       [array([[2, 2, 2],
               [2, 2, 2]]), array([[3, 3, 3],
                                   [3, 3, 3]])]], dtype=object)
```

Now the element arrays shapes can vary.

Generally I discourage the use of `vectorize` since it isn't real "vectorization".  It has a clear performance disclaimer.  And a object dtype array is little better, and in some ways worse, than a list.

```
In [196]: timeit f(np.arange(1000))
9.45 ms ± 67.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [197]: timeit [x*np.ones((2,3),int) for x in range(1000)]
9.46 ms ± 290 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [198]: timeit np.array([x*np.ones((2,3),int) for x in range(1000)])
9.83 ms ± 20.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

It used to be that `np.vectorize` was slower than the equivalent list comprehension.  Now it is still slower for small arguments, but it scales better.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation. The `otypes=['object']` would probably make it work. But about your last part, that's what I was beginning to realize. I will rewrite the algorithm without the vectorize.